# Change of Variables Bound on Integral

Tags: integration, inequality, operator-theory, integral-inequality, functional-inequalities

Let $f \in L^p_{\mathbb{P}}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and let $u:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ be continuous.  Can we bound
$$
\int_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} |f\circ u(x)|^p dx \leq C \int_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} |f(x)|^p dx,
$$
for some universal constant C depending only on $u$, $n$, and $p$?  If not in general, then in what cases where $u(x) \neq k x$ (for some $k \in \mathbb{R}$).

Comment: If $u$ is a homeomorphism then maybe the change-of-measure property of push-forward measures can be used to say something?

Comment: I tried something like that but it's not so clear to me

Comment: Is there supposed to be a constant multiplier in that inequality? Otherwise what do you mean by "for some universal constant"?